# python: get data from server with GET method from html

Tags: python, html, flask, get, webapi

I want to get data from HTML file.
I write in python using flask and mongoDB.
I need to demo a UI, and do it with basic html

I need to send a GET request to get data of specific user by his name.
my url I defined in app.py is `localhost:5000/employee/<name>`

In html, I create an input text field for user to put the name and then to *send* it to server and get the data.

How can I do it?
I tried with `<form>` tag and with `action` & `method` attribute, but it is not good :(

any help?
thanks!

Comment: Is there a specific question?  It kind of sounds like you might want a getting started tutorial for Flask and that would be beyond the scope of what this site typically answers. Maybe check out : https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/

Comment: Use `requests.get()` to get the HTML data, and Beautiful Soup to parse it.

Comment: @JonSG it is an excellent guide but it is not for me. i search for a tutorial how to call my python GetFunc() that return the data, from HTML! not from python.

thanks

Comment: @Barmar the script tag in html doesn't allow me to use requests.get()
thanks

Comment: If there's JS updating the DOM dynamically, use Selenium WebDriver to execute it.

Comment: If you're trying to emulate a form submission, they usually use `POST`, not `GET`.